# How to upgrade Postgresql 11.2 to 11.17 on Ubunutu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

We have a Ubuntu 14.04 server with Postgresql 11.2 installed. We need to upgrade it to 11.17. I have read old versions of Postgresql will move to https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/. So I have updated the sources.list to point to above. But I cannot see any latest packages other than 11.3.

[image: apt-cache policy postgresql-11]

Is there a way I can install 11.17 or is it supported at all. If not what should be my approach to have latest Postgresql.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 is on extended security maintenance [since 2019](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle).  You should not expect minor point releases of postgresql to be released or supported.  The archive you have found is simply archiving old versions which were released.  Since newer versions are not now being released for 14.04 they won't make it into the archive for 14.04.

The extended security maintenance only covers patching security vulnerabilities.

At this point in time your options are really limited.  You can:

- [Install postgresql 11.17 from source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/installation.html)
- Upgrade the OS to a newer version (or completely rebuild the box/vm). You might need to experiment how new you can go with the other software on the machine.  If possible try to upgrade to the current LTS to make sure you don't hit the same problem again in 2 years time.
- Leave it as-is.  When you work with old systems like this, sometimes the outcome is to decide that all options are too complex and to just leave it until the system is fully replaced.